# Why my flask app is not redirecting after AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

I am making a web app to help disabled people to navigate the internet. It is taking voice command through a JavaScript and sending the command to the Python app.py Flask app. However, weirdly enough it is not redirecting in any way and giving me 500 internal server error.

This is the JavaScript function which sends command -

```
// This function sends command to python
function sendCommand(command){
    let userCommand = {
        "command": command
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/command",
        data: JSON.stringify(userCommand),
        contentType: "application/JSON",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(){
            window.location.href = "temp.html";
        }        
    })
}
```

And this is the python flask app -

```
# Importing required libraries and functions
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys

# Initiating Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# Command Global variable
COMMAND = ""

# Route to Command (Index) page
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

# Processing Command
@app.route('/command', methods=["POST"])
def get_javascript_data():
    if request.method == "POST":
        JSONdict = request.get_json()
        COMMAND = JSONdict["command"]
        print(f'{COMMAND}', file=sys.stdout)

        if "search" in COMMAND:
            print("TODOSearch")
        elif ("music" and "play") in COMMAND:
            print("TODO")
        else:
            print("TODO")
            
        return redirect("/redirect")

@app.route("/redirect")
def redirect():
    return render_template("redirect.html")
```

What is my fault over here?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to redirect from flask on a POST request. Instead use `return 200`

Then the success function in your Ajax request should trigger.

If you need more flexibility, you can also return json data to the "success" or "error" function.
`return json.dumps({'success' : True}), 200, {'ContentType' : 'application/json'}`